# Changing datetime format in csv files - Batch Scripting/ Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, datetime-format

[Changing datetime format in csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595779/changing-datetime-format-in-csv-files/61672405#61672405)
This solution works only if date value in all rows have a value.
What is the modified script to handle if null values are passed ?
Also, the solution is if 3rd field is date format.
WHat if I have 4th and 5th fields also as dates and I have to change them as well.

Comment: Use [DateTime.TryParse()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393630/503046) to, well, try to parse a date. If the value is null,it can't be parsed as a date.

Comment: Do your csv files have column headers? Can **any** field have a date you need to convert? Please show the first 3 or 4 lines of such a csv file. Not as comment, but edit your question instead and paste it in there.

Answer (score 1):

If your csv files have proper column headers, then using **PowerShell** you can do the following to look for any field in the file having a date in `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format and update it with the preferred format `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` like this:

```
$sourceFolder = 'X:\Path\to\where\the\csv\files\are'
$testDate     = Get-Date  # just any DateTime object to use with TryParseExact()

# get the files from the path and loop through
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $csv = Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName

    # get the header names from the first row
    $headers  = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
    # loop through all data rows in the csv. (each row is a PSObject with properties)
    foreach($item in $csv) {
        # loop through all properties (fields) in the item
        foreach($name in $headers) {
            # see if this is a date in the expected format
            if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($item.$name, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt',[cultureinfo]"en-US", 0, [ref]$testDate)) {
                $item.$name = '{0:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}' -f $testDate
            }
        }
    }
    # if you like, output on screen
    $csv | Format-Table -AutoSize

    # output to new CSV file
    $out = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ('{0}-Updated{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
    $csv | Export-Csv -Path $out -NoTypeInformation
}
```